# SonarQube /api/resources - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: jenkins, sonarqube, jenkins-plugins, sonarqube-scan

I'm using the [slack-sonar-pusher][1] on the Jenkins, but when I run the job I got this output:

```
 [ssp] Calling SonarQube on: http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:9000/api/resources?metrics=alert_status,quality_gate_details&includealerts=true
 [ssp] Got a non 200 response from SonarQube. Server responded with '500 : Internal Server Error'
 [ssp] Could not get Sonar results, exception: 'null'
 Build step 'Sonar Slack pusher' marked build as failure
```

If I open the http://xxx.xxx.x.xx:9000/api/resources?metrics=alert_status,quality_gate_details&includealerts=true url directly into the browser, I received the **right content** :

```
<resource>
<id>1</id>
<key>xxxxxx</key>
<name>xxxxx</name>
<lname>xxxxx</lname>
<scope>PRJ</scope>
<qualifier>TRK</qualifier>
<version>1.0</version>
<date>2016-04-15T17:54:33+0200</date>
<creationDate>2016-04-13T18:15:34+0200</creationDate>
<msr>
<key>alert_status</key>
<data>ERROR</data>
<alert>ERROR</alert>
<alert_text>
New Blocker issues > 0 since previous version (2016 Apr 13), New Critical issues > 20 since previous version (2016 Apr 13)
</alert_text>
</msr>
<msr>
<key>quality_gate_details</key>
<data>
{"level":"ERROR","conditions":[{"metric":"new_blocker_violations","op":"GT","period":1,"error":"0","actual":"3","level":"ERROR"},{"metric":"new_critical_violations","op":"GT","period":1,"warning":"","error":"20","actual":"71","level":"ERROR"},{"metric":"new_sqale_debt_ratio","op":"GT","period":1,"error":"5","actual":"0.0","level":"OK"}]}
</data>
</msr>
</resource>
```

**Sonar.log**

```
2016.04.15 19:07:39 ERROR web[o.s.s.ui.JRubyFacade] Fail to render: http://xxx.xx.x.xxx:9000/api/resources?metrics=alert_status,quality_gate_details&includealerts=true
undefined method `generate' for #<JSON::Ext::Generator::State:0x6157370a>
    /Users/Jenkins/.calabash/calabash-gems/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:223:in `generate'
    /Users/Jenkins/.calabash/calabash-gems/gems/json-1.8.3/lib/json/common.rb:470:in `JSON'
    /private/etc/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:48:in `jsonp'
    /private/etc/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:132:in `error_to_json'
    /private/etc/sonarqube-5.4/web/WEB-INF/app/controllers/api/api_controller.rb:123:in `render_response'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:290:in `call'
    org/jruby/RubyProc.java:224:in `call'
```

Anyone any idea what can be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLVED**:

```
unset GEM_PATH
unset GEM_HOME
```